# Create iterable list from very large number of entries

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a file that has well over 600,000 entries. It basically contains:

```
user1 choice1
user1 choice2
user2 choice3
user2 choice1
.
.
.
.
user400000 choice60
```

When I try to create a dictionary by usual methods (shown below), idle stops responding.

```
d = {}
with open("file.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
       (key, val) = line.split()
       d[key] = val
```

I want an easily and quickly manipulatable list/dictionary from this large file of entries. What would be the most efficient way to get that?

Comment: This should work, assuming that all the types are right.  Are you maybe printing out `d` -- which you didn't show -- afterwards?  That could lock up IDLE.  Try `print len(d)` after that loop.

Comment: You want to manipulate how?  The problem is that you are trying to store the "large file" in a variable.  It would be best if you can do the manipulation one line at a time and not store it. But that may not be feasible.

Comment: @bernie: Damn, you saw it faster :D

Comment: @bernie Sorry about that. I have been playing with numpy and had lost my original code. So I just found something similar, to give a sense of what I am dealing with. Didn't notice the int.

Comment: @cmd I want to return a list of usernames and the choices that qualifies (i.e. has not been picked before). so basically choice1, choice2 are available for user1 but not available for user2.

Comment: Consider using [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org)

Comment: @Boud Could you give me a basic idea of how I should go about using panda? Does it have specific functions/methods I should look more into?

Comment: @poverFlow12 `pandas.read_table` or `pandas.read_csv` should do for you. [Here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html) are the docs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org) allows to manipulate this amount of data easily. Your data is a series of `user` labels with a scalar data point associated to it.

```
import pandas as pd
s = pd.read_csv('file.txt', sep=' ', header=None, index_col=0, squeeze=True)
```

This instruction asks `pandas` to load the file data into a Series object:

- columns are space separated (`sep=' '`)
- the file has no title header and the first line is already data (`header=None`)
- we want to manipulate the date with the first column as an index (`index_col=0`)
- by default, `pandas` builds a `DataFrame` object, but if it contains a single column of data, we can ask for a `Series` instead (`squeeze=True`)

`s` is a `Series` object indexed on the user labels we can now use to access the data:

```
In [37]: s.head()
Out[37]: 
0
user0    104106
user1     31024
user2     82993
user3    211414
user4    499070
Name: 1

In [38]: s['user3']
Out[38]: 211414
```

With a `'file.txt'`of 600000 lines, it took around a second to load `s`. Following dict-like accesses on `s` are immediate.